# Chromium Embedded 64 bit build

Tags: c++, visual-c++, google-chrome

Where to get this build. V8 & Chromium both compile against 64 bits. So why are there no 64 bit builds out ?

I don't like using IE in my applications. For obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google seem to be working on the Windows 64-bit port (if that's the one you mean) - this bug has been assigned: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8606

Answer (score 1):

You can build both Chromium and V8 as x64 builds in Linux, it's just not supported on Windows. From the [Chromium Design Document](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/64-bit-support) under '64-bit support':

> A 64-bit version of Chromium can be built on Linux by using the `-Dtarget_arch=x64` flag on the GYP build system.  (This is the default on 64-bit Linux systems.)
>
> The 64-bit version of  the V8 JavaScript engine used by Chromium can be built separately using the `--arch=x64` flag in v8's Scons build system. This works on both the Linux and Mac OS X platforms.
>
> Neither Chromium nor V8 has a 64-bit version on the Windows platform right now. However, Chrome does run on 64-bit Windows as a 32-bit application. V8 should only need a small number of changes to build on the Windows platform.

Comment: v8 can be built in 64 bit. Chromium can't, yet.